# CSS, why is the picture below the other picture?

Tags: html, css, web, sass, pug

[my project](http://hansmagz.github.io) on the Academics section, why does the animating thumb are below the thumb on it's right side?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot indicating what you're referring to?

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/9I3ImHI.jpg)

Comment: All the external links are broken in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Add the css property `overflow: hidden;` to the wrapping element.

[image]

Comment: The same principle of use `overflow:hidden` maybe on the individual elements may be worth a shot .

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
  -webkit-animation-name: tada;
          animation-name: tada;
```

This changes the size of user image for 1s and then sets it to a normal size.
Maybe you want to remove it, or pick another animation?

Comment: I don't want to remove the animation, but I'll try to pick another animation, thanks

Comment: I picked another animation at [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) but still not fixed

Answer (score 0):

[My Project](http://hansmagz.github.io/), It's fixed, I don't know how but i just rewrites the code then it worked, thanks